# WSDL parsing using XSOMParser error

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, wsdl

I have a WSDL file and am using XSOMParser to parse the file. But it is giving some exception.

My code is :

```
private void initXsom() throws IOException {
        try {
            SchemaImpl schema = (SchemaImpl) wsdlObject.getTypes()
                    .getExtensibilityElements().get(0);

            Element el = schema.getElement();
            InputStream is = prepareSchema(el);

            XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();

            // is needed to read element documentations which are inside
            // annotations
            parser.setAnnotationParser(new AnnotationFactory());

            parser.parse(is);

            String targetNamespace = wsdlObject.getTargetNamespace();
            if (parser.getResult() == null)
                throw new IOException(
                        "Could not initialize XML Schema");
            schemaObject = parser.getResult().getSchema(targetNamespace);

            addSchemaElements();

        } catch (TransformerException | SAXException e) {
            throw new IOException("Problem initializing XML Schema.", e);
        }

    }
```

It is giving me the exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Problem initializing XML Schema.
    at eu.impact_project.iif.ws.generic.WsdlDocument.initXsom(WsdlDocument.java:170)
    at eu.impact_project.iif.ws.generic.WsdlDocument.<init>(WsdlDocument.java:105)
    at eu.impact_project.iif.ws.generic.SoapService.<init>(SoapService.java:57)
    at eu.impact_project.iif.ws.generic.SoapService.<init>(SoapService.java:47)
    at soapUi.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:20)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.JAXPParser.parse(JAXPParser.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:102)
    at eu.impact_project.iif.ws.generic.WsdlDocument.initXsom(WsdlDocument.java:158)
```

Can anyone please help me out from this.
Thanks

Comment: your WSDL may have been corrupt. The error clearly shows the problem at the very first line. also check the schema that the WSDL is using. the WSDL should be as per the schema decleration

Comment: I am using Adobe echosign web services and the url of their wsdl is:

https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService19?wsdl

I am not sure but it’s highly improbable that it would be corrupt.